# jupyter notebook cannot run on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, jupyter

After pip install jupyter

`$ jupyter notebook`

I cannot run jupyter-notebook correctly.The error I get is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1071, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 919, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 153, in bind_sockets
    0, flags)):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 4] Non-recoverable failure in name resolution`

Comment: Which version of jupyter notebook are you running?

Comment: @rtk22 version 4.2.0

Comment: Try `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1` and if that fails then `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0`

Comment: @rtk22 you're right.I've solved the problem.Thank you!

Comment: If this is your first time, try installing Anaconda package manager, which comes with jupyter.  https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 1):

After checking /etc/hosts, I delete the wrong localhost record though have no idea who add it.

before:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::10    localhost
```

after:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

And now jupyter notebook is working.